# how to keep the line number when using bag.read_text to read multiple files?

Tags: python, dask, distributed, dask-distributed, bag

I want to read multiple .txt files by bag.read_text and record the file path and the line number of each line for some more processing.
The `read_text` function has an argument `include_path=True` which can keep the path, but how can I get the line number? Will the read_text() keep the line order after reading files?

```py
def add_line_number(element):
    line, path = element

    # how to get the line number?
    line_index = ...
    return line, path, line_index

b = db.read_text([file1, file2, ...], blocksize='10 MiB', include_path)
b = b.map(add_line_number).compute()
# expect b to be: [('line 1', 'file path', ith line in that file), ...]
```

**Edit2**
Thanks for your help. Here are further questions.
Does the `read_text` guarantee to preserve line order in each partition when assigning files_per_partition=1?
In the source code, file seems to be read line by line

```
with OpenFile as f:
    for line in f:
        yield line or (line, path)
```

Will the parallelization affect it's sequence or this job will only be executed by one worker?

Answer (score 2):

What you want is not really possible. When dask splits up a large file, it reads from arbitrary offsets (10MB in your example) and assumes that the next newline character is marks a new line. Thus, it cannot know, for this chunks (which gets processed with the previous chunks in parallel), how many lines preceded it.

You can easily enough enumerate the lines of a given chunks (with `.map_partitions()`, not `.map()`), and you can find the number of lines in all chunks, but not in a single pass. To find the number of lines per chunk:

```
b.map_partitions(len).compute()
```

Comment: Wouldn't using `files_per_partition=1` kwarg help to resolve the across-files partitioning issue?

Comment: Actually, you'd need to increase the blocksize (or give `None`) to include whole files and enable line number from the start of the file (but no parallelism). You still wouldn't know the number of lines since the start of the whole dataset.

Comment: Thanks for you help. Does read_text preserve the order among blocks when reading file block-wise?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean - they are processed in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not what you are looking for, but a non-Python option is to use `nl`:

```sh
cat some_file.txt | nl -s "," -w 1 > new_file.txt
```

The options are:

- `-w 1` (to avoid blank spaces between line number and line content),
- `-s ","` (to use comma as a delimiter).

For example:

```sh
seq 3 | nl -s "," -w 1
#1,1
#2,2
#3,3
```

Later, these modified files could be processed with `dask.bag`. This is not optimal, since storage requirements increase, but it might be a workable solution if one really needs consecutive line numbers per file.

It can also be modified to attach sequential numbers across multiple files:

```sh
cat *.txt | nl -s "," -w 1 > big_file.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, but it seems not work in my case because all my work will be executed on remote so I want to keep resource usage in a low level.